# Proof of LU decomposition of a special matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How do we show that the following LU decomposition is true with the help of matrix multiplication? How can we characterize the rows of the U matrix while doing the multiplication?

[image]

Comment: this question would be a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Workout the multiplication on the right hand side and you should get the left hand side matrix. I would call this "Verifying a LU composition" not proving.